# Lambda expression to add XElement into Dictionary

Tags: c#, xml, lambda

I have to put XElement xelement with value [ABC INC, False] into `Dictionary<string, bool?>`

I ended up with a code :

```
Dictionary<string, bool?> LogicalDistinctValues;
            foreach (XElement xelement in lvalues.Elements())
            {
                string[] vals = xelement.Value.Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty).Split(',');
                if (vals.Count() == 2)
                {
                    string val;
                    bool lval;
                    val = vals[0];
                    if( bool.TryParse(vals[1], out lval))
                    {
                        LogicalDistinctValues.Add(val, lval);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LogicalDistinctValues.Add(val, true);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Is it possible to replace it with a lambda expression?

Comment: You don't need the `ToString()` before the `Split()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing something ugly here, something that you shouldn't ever do. This code is slower than your code, and uglier.

```
bool lval;

Dictionary<string, bool?> LogicalDistinctValues =
    (from xelement in lvalues.Elements()
        let vals = xelement.Value.Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty).Split(',')
        where vals.Length == 2
        select new { Key = vals[0], Value = bool.TryParse(vals[1], out lval) ? (bool?)lval : true }
    ).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
}
```

Note that I'm doing a bad thing... I'm doing a `out` to a local variable. This is normally morally wrong to do in a LINQ expression.

As a sidenote, you used a useless `.ToString()` and instead of `.Count()` you should use `.Length` for arrays.

Note that I'm creating the `Dictionary<>` from scratch. If you need to add the elements to a preexisting array, then you can't do it directly in LINQ (because `Dictionary<>` doesn't have a `AddRange`)... You could do a `foreach` with the result of the `select`.

```
var exp = from xelement in lvalues.Elements()
            let vals = xelement.Value.Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty).Split(',')
            where vals.Length == 2
            select new { Key = vals[0], Value = bool.TryParse(vals[1], out lval) ? (bool?)lval : true };

foreach (var kv in exp)
{
    LogicalDistinctValues.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do something like this. It is a bit ugly but in this way you will do it in one go:

```
bool lval;
var LogicalDistinctValues= (
        from xelement in lvalues.Elements()
        let vals = xelement.Value.Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty).ToString().Split(',')
        where vals.Count () ==2
        select new
        {
            Key= vals[0],
            Value=bool.TryParse(vals[1],out lval)?lval:true
        }
    ).ToDictionary (l =>l.Key,l=>l.Value);
```